# Laravel: проверка формата полей когда хотя бы одно из них обязательно для ввода

Tags: php, laravel

Допустим, мы хотим спросить через форму ввода у пользователя *хотя бы* один из двух контактов: телефон и/или адрес электронной почты. Это значит, что в правилах валидации будет правило `required_without` для обоих полей:

```
$this->validate($request, [

    'email' => 'required_without:tel|email',
    'tel' => 'required_without:email|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/'

], $messages);
```

Нам необходимо валидировать формат данных только тогда, когда они введены, но в коде выше формат проверяется всегда. Поскольку нам нужно знать хотя бы один контакт, то правило `sometimes` не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать правило `bail`.

Если указано правило, то валидатор не пойдет дальше если предыдущее правило не отработало, возможно в вашем случае он поможет:

```
$this->validate($request, [

    'email' => 'bail|required_without:tel|email',
    'tel' => 'bail|required_without:email|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/'

], $messages);
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Разве "Валидатор не пойдёт дальше" не означает, что данные будут невалидными, а потому отправки не прозойдёт?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu он не пойдет дальше по текущему полю, то есть если `required_without:tel` не верно то уже `email` не будет проверять и пойдет проверять `tel`, и аналогично с полем `tel`, а вам это как раз и нужно

Comment: Вы всё правильно говорите, но не работат - всё равно проходит проверку на формат. Я понял, почему: если хотя бы одно из полей заполнено, `required_without` возвращает `true` для обоих полей, а потому `bail` не останавливает проверку и она доходит по последнего условия.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu попробуйте может для email `required_if:tel,` и аналогично для email, запятая в конце специально потому что 2 параметр на пустоту проверяем, в теории должно отработать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать правило `nullable`

```
$this->validate($request, [

    'email' => 'nullable|required_without:tel|email',
    'tel' => 'nullable|required_without:email|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/'

], $messages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо использовать правила `required_without_all` и `nullable`

```
$this->validate($request, [

    'email' => 'required_without_all:tel|email|nullable',
    'tel' => 'required_without_all:email|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/|nullable'

], $messages);
```

[Источник](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-without-all)